# Setting a table name in a model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Im trying to pass in a table name to my model, as the model operates on two tables, but has the same methods.

I do it like so:

```
$this->model = new Emotions(array('section' => 'red'));
```

And in the model I set the table like:

```
public function __construct($attributes = array(), $exists = false){

    parent::__construct($attributes, $exists);
    $this->table = $attributes['section'];
}
```

But I get the error:

```
Undefined index: section
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Strange. I've tested it and your code works fine. Have you tried to pass a non associative array to see if works? Pass array('red') and see if you can access it as attributes[0]. Is there any change of using different character sets?

Comment: No - Undefined offset: 0

Comment: The thing is, I can var_dump out $attributes['section'] and the right output is given, its only when I try and set $table does it fail.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i get it, This class maybe running twice.

Please try this.

```
public function __construct($attributes = array(), $exists = false){

    parent::__construct($attributes, $exists);

    if(isset($attributes['section'])) {
        $this->table = $attributes['section'];
    }
}
```

My personal suggestion

```
<?php

class Emotions extends Eloquent
{
    public function setTableName($name)
    {
        $this->table = $name;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And you can use like this

```
$emotion = new Emotions(array('foo' => 'bar'))
    ->setTableName('blabla')
    ->save();
```

Answer (score -1):

add below line to your class.

```
protected $fillable = array('section');
```

http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Nothing to do with the question.